# How to Extract detected in Release name or detected in cycle name from HP ALM using rest API?

Tags: rest, alm, hp-alm, defects

I am developing an application that extracts defects from HP ALM using rest api call.

Detected in Release and Detected in Cycle has ID stored and not able to extract their reference by value.. Could you please help me to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below URLs to get the releases and releases-cycles collection.

/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/releases
/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/release-cycles

You may refer the below documentation page for further information.

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/Content/REST_API_Tech_Preview/General/Overview.html

[image]